# SKImage running very slowly and outputting unexpected results

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm using scikit-Image for the first time for use in a hackathon this weekend. While doing some tests I found that the api is running very slowly despite at the bottom of [the page](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_morphsnakes.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-morphsnakes-py) saying their script runtime was 4.780 seconds. Every time I run mine it takes upwards of 20 minutes.

Their example code wasn't working for me as I couldn't get matplotlib to work. I have tried to adapt it and have been using PIL to save my images

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage import data, img_as_float, img_as_ubyte
from skimage.segmentation import (morphological_chan_vese, 
morphological_geodesic_active_contour, inverse_gaussian_gradient, 
checkerboard_level_set)

def store_evolution_in(lst):
    """Returns a callback function to store the evolution of the 
level sets in
    the given list.
    """

    def _store(x):
        lst.append(np.copy(x))

    return _store

imarray = np.asarray(Image.open("./images/bottle.jpg"))
# Morphological ACWE
image = img_as_float(imarray)
# Initial level set
init_ls = checkerboard_level_set(image.shape, 6)
# List with intermediate results for plotting the evolution
evolution = []
callback = store_evolution_in(evolution)

gimage = inverse_gaussian_gradient(image)
ls = morphological_geodesic_active_contour(gimage, 100, init_ls,
                                       smoothing=1, balloon=-1,
                                       threshold=0.69,
                                       iter_callback=callback)
intls = img_as_ubyte(ls)
Image.fromarray(intls).save('./results/ls.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

I'm hoping to get back a segmented image like they have in their results (end goal is to only have the dark liquid in a bottle left over). But not only is the runtime much longer then theirs, it only returns a black image. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

My Activity Monitor says Python is consuming 100% of CPU power but the CPU Load at the bottom says User is consuming 9%, so I can only assume not all of my cores are being used.

Comment: Do you mind filing an issue at https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image?  Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the image that you are testing this on?